# Определение падежа в названии организации

Tags: падежи

Мы изменили название организации на "Региональная(ую) ссоциация(ю) любителей животных". По идее: на кого? что? ассоциацию. Затрудняюсь, в общем, с падежом. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в кавычках, то согласование по падежам не обязательно.

Answer (score 2):

А нельзя ли немного перестроить предложение. Например, так: *Мы изменили название организации. Теперь оно звучит так: "Региональная ассоциация любителей животных".* Если речь идет об официально-деловом стиле, то лучше название приводить в именительном падеже (что требует перестройки предложения).